# copy row values and paste into next empty row until it finds next value python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to copy the value of the first-row value into the following until the next value is met and then copy the next one and replicate the same process.
the initial data frame is as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, '',''], ['', '', 'nunu','lala'], ['', '', 'tata','toto'],[7, 8, '',''],['', '', 'zaza','zeze'],['', '', 'yyu','uyuy'],['', '', 'rfrf','gbgb']]),
               columns=['a', 'b', 'c','d'])
```

and the result would be like this

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 'nunu','lala'], [1, 2, 'tata','toto'],[7, 8, 'zaza','zeze'],[7, 8, 'yyu','uyuy'],[7, 8, 'rfrf','gbgb']]),
               columns=['a', 'b', 'c','d'])
```

Is this doable in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

try replacing empty character to 'NaN' then forward+backword fill then drop duplicates:

```
df=df.replace('',float('NaN')).ffill().bfill().drop_duplicates(['c'])
```

output of df:

```
    a   b   c       d
0   1   2   nunu    lala
2   1   2   tata    toto
4   7   8   zaza    zeze
5   7   8   yyu     uyuy
6   7   8   rfrf    gbgb
```

Comment: I didn't know the `float('NaN')`, nice one, I'll steal it ;)

Comment: @mozway feel free to steal it ***;)***

Comment: @Seph77 glad it helped...Happy coding **:)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and slicing:

```
# replace empty strings with NaN
df2 = df.replace('', float('nan'))
# keep index of rows to drop
idx = df2['c'].isna()
# fill forward, drop unwanted rows and reset_index
df2.ffill()[~idx].reset_index()
```

output:

```
    a   b   c       d
0   1   2   nunu    lala
2   1   2   tata    toto
4   7   8   zaza    zeze
5   7   8   yyu     uyuy
6   7   8   rfrf    gbgb
```